# Why do nodes only discover each other but do not connect when run from different computer on the same network

Tags: node.js, libp2p

I am trying to get up to speed with js-libp2p and I am poking around with this code snippet:

```
const Libp2p = require("libp2p")
const WebSockets = require('libp2p-websockets')
const Tcp = require('libp2p-tcp')
const { NOISE } = require('libp2p-noise')
const MPLEX = require('libp2p-mplex')
const Mdns = require('libp2p-mdns')
async function main() {
 
const node = await Libp2p.create({
  modules: {
      transport: [WebSockets, Tcp],
      connEncryption: [NOISE],
      streamMuxer: [MPLEX],
      peerDiscovery: [Mdns]
  },
  addresses: {
      listen: [
          '/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/0/ws',
          '/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/0',
      ]
  }
})
await node.start()
 
node.on('peer:discovery', (peer) => {
  console.log(`Discovered ${peer}`)
})
node.connectionManager.on('peer:connect', (connection) => {
   console.log(`Connection established ${connection.remotePeer.toB58String()}`)
})
 
}
main()
```

If I run it from two consoles *on the same computer*, on starting the second console I get the following expected output:

```
Discovered bafzbeia7bnohivu4lnyvzd5f4vix2xsru4sidmgitcp5u2ysepxwct5rwu
Connection established QmQRqPvVKDYUKrNYc8SsFwyK2kkxq3zUSojvmDUqNzoy32
Connection established QmQRqPvVKDYUKrNYc8SsFwyK2kkxq3zUSojvmDUqNzoy32
Connection established QmQRqPvVKDYUKrNYc8SsFwyK2kkxq3zUSojvmDUqNzoy32
```

and from the other console also:

```
Discovered bafzbeieeqfz3whgaj7hbxbczkxs3vue2yxid4cwpdqkrtzcrpkmepuqzj4
Connection established QmXFu1kP9wWu42vtREEdXhdWc4uLHZ4t5r3fYtfbmb66y4
Connection established QmXFu1kP9wWu42vtREEdXhdWc4uLHZ4t5r3fYtfbmb66y4
Connection established QmXFu1kP9wWu42vtREEdXhdWc4uLHZ4t5r3fYtfbmb66y4
```

But if I move the same script and run it on another computer on the same network, I only see the Discovered log. The connection log never gets printed out. For example I only see this:

```
➜  my_node node node.js
Discovered bafzbeienf65d3slqvblq3sqoedltuqorakqfkdnyodocul52gptdrqhqx4
```

Does anybody have an explanation why this is the case? And also what do I need to do to have full connection? Because as I poke around with libp2p I would prefer to have the nodes run on two computers.

Also maybe explain the difference between `peer:discovery` event and `peer:connect` event? I mean how is peer discovery different from peer connected?

PS: Also I noticed that the connection log keeps getting printed at interval. Why is that also the case?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it turned out the problem was me listening to the loopback address. That is 127.0.0.1. Replacing it with `0.0.0.0` solved the problem. Hence changing from:

```
          '/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/0/ws',
          '/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/0',
```

to

```
          '/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0/ws',
          '/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0',
```